# Trouble sending boto3 filtered data to a list

Tags: python, anaconda, boto3

I've generated a working boto3 instance filter using anaconda python 2.7. I need to assign the IP addresses and instance names to a list for further processing.

Code looks like this:

```
for instance in instances:
    print(instance.id, instance.instance_type, instance.key_name, instance.private_ip_address, instance.public_dns_name ,instance.tags[0].get("Value"))

tagged   = ec2.instances.filter(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:My', 'Values': ['tag']}])

for instance in tagged:
    print(name, instance.id, instance.private_ip_address)

object_list={}
object_list['requests']=[]

for instance in tagged:
        tagged.collections.OrderedDict()
        tagged['ip-address'] = instance.private_ip_address
        tagged['machine'] = name
        tagged['roles'] = ['tagged',instance.id,name]
        object_list['requests'].append(tagged)
```

This is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'ec2.instancesCollection' object has no attribute 'collections'
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this doesn't exist but you have a cryptic error because you are reusing your `tagged` variable which is an instance of `ec2.instancesCollection`

```
 tagged.collections.OrderedDict()
```

(and would do nothing anyway since it's not affected)

you (probably) want/wanted:

```
tagged = collections.OrderedDict()
```

but that doesn't make sense since you're already iterating on `tagged`.

You have to declare another variable

```
for instance in tagged:
    t = collections.OrderedDict()
    t['ip-address'] = instance.private_ip_address
    t['machine'] = name
    t['roles'] = ['tagged',instance.id,name]
    object_list['requests'].append(t)
```